# Jquery removing target based on device

Tags: jquery

I have links to external sites on articles for readers to view more info - these are set to open in a new window using target=_blank. We have had a small number of reports that when this link is clicked on a iPhone/iPad it opens a new tab/window but the page does not appear it just hangs.

Not all iPhones or iPads are seeing this issue and looks to be dependent on the version of Safari used - though am not positive.

After reading up and to try avoid this happening I have cobbled together the following code and wanted to know whether this would work or whether there was a better approach?

```
    if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().match(/(ipad|iphone)/)) {    
    $('[target]').removeAttr('target');
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this plugin, it's much better than create you a script which detect the device. http://www.jqueryscript.net/other/jQuery-Browser-Mobile-Device-Detector-Plugin-jQuery-Browser.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply! After calling the plugin would my code then look something like this: if ($.browser.iphone) {
    
$('[target]').removeAttr('target');
}  How would I add so that it checks ipad as well?

Comment: Yes. That's the syntax for the ipad  $.browser.ipad. Please check also http://www.jqueryscript.net/other/jQuery-Browser-Mobile-Device-Detector-Plugin-jQuery-Browser.html#

Comment: Yes sorry I meant if I want to check both would it be like this: if ($.browser.iphone||$.browser.ipad) { $('[target]').removeAttr('target'); } thanks again